# New APK-version and wrong Layouts

Tags: android, xml, google-play, apk, android-manifest

I've just uploaded a new APK in my Developer Console. With new versionCode="2"
and new versionName="1.01".
I've changed nothing at the compatible screens:

```
<compatible-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

But when i Upload it in the Developer Console, the xlargeScreens are supported now:
[Picture in Google Play Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yjK.png)

Why are the xlarge-Screens supported now??

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it works.

No idea whats the matter with the Code above.

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true">

</supports-screens>
<compatible-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true">

</compatible-screens>
```